# Can't remove from git nonexistent file

Tags: git

I typed 'git status' in console:

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    app/controllers/api/v1/appication_controller.rb
#
```

I decided to remove this file:

```
git rm app/controllers/api/v1/application_controller.rb
```

But I got the following error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'app/controllers/api/v1/application_controller.rb' did not match any files
```

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
git rm --cached app/controllers/api/v1/application_controller.rb
```

It's already removed from the disk, so you only have to remove it in the staging area to make Git recognize the removal.

Comment: @malcoauri Make sure you don't have a typo in the path name, then - this is the right command. (Also make sure you're in the top level directory of the repository when you enter the command, since it's using a relative path.)

Comment: Thanks dude! Sorry. It works! I'll mark your answer as right asap